# Restful and Eclipse: java.net down

Tags: eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I need to implement an easy restful service with eclipse.
On the web i found tutorial and guide but everyone suggest me to use Jersey framework as jax-rs implementation. The problem is that java.net is down, so i don't know how to do. I have downloaded Java EE but i need help for configurate eclipse and web.xml.

Comment: Yes. http://java.net has been closed. For Java EE projects, refer to https://javaee.github.io. For Jersey, refer to https://jersey.github.io.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Koushik Kothagal's Java Brains video tutorial very useful as a beginners guide to Java EE. https://javabrains.io/topics/javaee

Comment: Thank you , this is very helpfull!
Now I can start to create a project!